# Set different classes on click (in the most AngularJS way)

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs

I am currently learning AngularJS and already started a little project, which is basically an older project of mine, done in jQuery.

Everythings fine so far, but the last hours I wrapped my head around this area. In jQuery back then 5 minutes, but I have no idea what's the best way in AngularJS)

Here is my jQuery: A calendar view. It opens and closes days on click. Once a day is clicked it gets the class `opened`. Also there is the state `locked`, where I disable to open the day at all.

```
$('.mod-item').on('click', function(){
        if ($(this).find('.mod-item-day').not('.locked')) {
            if($(this).find('.mod-item-day').hasClass('open')){
                $(this).find('.mod-item-day').removeClass('open').addClass('opened');
            }else{
                $(this).find('.mod-item-day').addClass('open');
            }
        }
});
```

Here is the markup:

```
<ul class="mod">
    <li class="mod-item">
        <div class="mod-item-day opened"><span>1</span></div>
        <div class="mod-item-content">
            <img src="../images/present1_late.jpeg" alt="">
        </div>
    </li>
```

So my question is - what's the most AngularJS way to do it?

Comment: Also consider creating it as a component. http://angularjs.org/#create-components and http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive

Comment: thx for the tip - directives are on my angular roadmap, but too "complex" for me right now (see my basic question above) :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You do this basically the way shown in [the To Do example](http://angularjs.org/#todo-html) on the Angular website.

1. On the day's `div`, specify `ng-click="callbackInYourScopeCode()"`. In the To Do example, it's `ng-click="archive()"`
2. On the day's `div`'s `class`, include a property from your model. In the To Do example, for instance, there's `<span class="done-{{todo.done}}">{{todo.text}}</span>`. Note the property `todo.done`.
3. In your scope code, have the function (`callbackInYourScopeCode`) change your model's property (`done` in the To Do example).

Angular will call your scope code in response to a click, and then update the element based on changes to your model.

Comment: Hi, i feel stupid now. I did the tutorial side by side on my own - but never got this abstract thought of using this for this simple task. It worked, and much cleaner and simpler as my first tries!

Comment: @flrnz: Don't feel stupid, we've all been there. Glad this helped!